# /index.html should return 404 but shows nginx welcome page instead

Tags: nginx

I have some python applications served as sockets to nginx

```
upstream domain_server {
  server unix:/webapps/domain/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/domain/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/domain/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/domain/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/domain/media/;
    }

    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://domain_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/domain/static/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    listen   80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This works fine and does everything I need.

However, if I visit `domain.com/index.html` something strange happens... the Python application, when runned in dev environment, correctly returns 404. When behind Nginx, though, it returns the nginx default welcome page!

Why is this?

I've moved the `default` file in `sites-available`. No mention of index.html in any file in `sites-enabled`, and 404 works fine for other links (like `www.domain.com/index1.html`).

Comment: `index.html` is in the default root, and `location /` serves files from the default root. If you have no files installed at that location, you should remove the `if` conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not overwrite the `root` directive in your vhost file, so Nginx uses the default one (maybe `/var/www/html` or `/usr/share/nginx/html`)

You can either add to your `server` block (preferably)

```
root /webapps/domain/static;
```

or delete the `index.html` of your default root folder. You can find the default root folder by running `nginx -V` and append `/html` to the value of the `--prefix` parameter